# Is there a quick way to find shift value in rot algorithm

Tags: encryption, rotation

I was watching scene where eliot and mr robot decrypt text just by looking at it. I know rot is weak encryption and shift value can be find by increasing shift value  while decrypting one by one but, is there a quick way to find shift value? and how can one say surely encryption algorithm used is rot?

Answer (score 0):

Can you find the correct decryption by looking at this?

```
NBCM CM UH YRUGJFY
ocdn dn vi zsvhkgz
pdeo eo wj atwilha
qefp fp xk buxjmib
rfgq gq yl cvyknjc
sghr hr zm dwzlokd
this is an example
uijt jt bo fybnqmf
vjku ku cp gzcorng
wklv lv dq hadpsoh
xlmw mw er ibeqtpi
ymnx nx fs jcfruqj
znoy oy gt kdgsvrk
aopz pz hu lehtwsl
bpqa qa iv mfiuxtm
cqrb rb jw ngjvyun
drsc sc kx ohkwzvo
estd td ly pilxawp
ftue ue mz qjmybxq
guvf vf na rknzcyr
hvwg wg ob sloadzs
iwxh xh pc tmpbeat
jxyi yi qd unqcfbu
kyzj zj re vordgcv
lzak ak sf wpsehdw
mabl bl tg xqtfiex
```

Most of the time you don't even have to look at all 25 possible rotations.  It's even easier if you have a spellchecker on.